# Mapping DDD objects to EF Core results in InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I am trying to map my DDD Objects to my SQL Server database using Entity Framework Core. This works quiet fine, except when I set a `ValueObject` as `OwnsOne`. The migration runs through, the database gets updated but when I try to fetch a row, I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No backing field could be found for property 'LocalAudioSourcePath.LocalAudioSourceId' and the property does not have a getter.

```
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase.GetMemberInfo(Boolean forMaterialization, Boolean forSet)  
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.ClrPropertyGetterFactory.Create(IPropertyBase property)  
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RuntimePropertyBase.<>c.<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase.GetGetter>b__35_0(RuntimePropertyBase property)  
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RuntimePropertyBase.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase.GetGetter()
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.ParameterValueExtractor[T](QueryContext context, String baseParameterName, IProperty property)
 at lambda_method788(Closure, QueryContext)
 at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I try to share as much code as I can, so if you need more information, just tell me.

These are the relevant classes:

```cs
public sealed class LocalAudioSource : AudioSource
{
    public LocalAudioSource(AudioSourceId id) : base(id) { }

    public required LocalAudioSourcePath Path { get; set; }
}

public sealed class LocalAudioSourcePath : ValueObject
{
    public string AbsolutePath { get; private set; }

    #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    private LocalAudioSourcePath() { }
    #pragma warning restore CS8618 

    private LocalAudioSourcePath(string absolutePath)
    {
        AbsolutePath = absolutePath;
    }

    public static LocalAudioSourcePath Create(string path)
    {
        return new(path);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return AbsolutePath;
    }
}

public class LocalAudioSourceTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<LocalAudioSource>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LocalAudioSource> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("LocalAudioSources");
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => AudioSourceId.FromGuid(value));

        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Path);
    }
}
```

I followed a tutorial of [Amichai Mantinband on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_un3PUER8U&t=819s&ab_channel=AmichaiMantinband) and I can't see any difference.

## Update 1

I created a sample project which I wanted to share, but here it worked as expected. Then I narrowed down the issue and I think I found it.

```
return await _context.LocalAudioSources
            .Include(e => e.Directories)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.AccountId == accountId && e.Path == path, cancellationToken);
```

What I am doing here is I am comparing ValueObjects directly, which should be fine, but EF does not use the custom Equals method. This results in the Exception I posted earlier. What made the code work is editing the EF code like this:

```cs
return await _context.LocalAudioSources
            .Include(e => e.Directories)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.AccountId == accountId && e.Path.AbsolutePath == path.AbsolutePath, cancellationToken);
```

Here we are comparing the actual value. This is not a good solution, but it works. I would be fine with it, but maybe someone knows how to also overcome this

Comment: The error is pretty clear: EF cannot find the `LocalAudioSourceId` field on `LocalAudioSourcePath` class, and I suppose is the primary key.

Comment: Thats what I thought at first too, but the thing is, that the `LocalAudioSourcePath` does not have a primary key, because it is used with OwnsOne

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of your DB? Here the [OwnsOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) docs

Comment: What exactly do you need? An image of the DB tables which are generated?
If you mean some code, it is within `LocalAudioSourceTypeConfiguration` with line `builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Path);`. Thats where I set the `OwnsOne` configuration.

Comment: @DirtyNative EF Core version? `AudioSource` class (enity?), `AudioSourceId` , `ValueObject` - basically everything we can copy/paste and reproduce. I suspect the problem to be caused by the "typed id" (one DDD concept not very well supported by EFC), but have to be 100% sure.

Comment: I can also create a sample project, this would help more I guess. Give me some hours, I will share it as soon as I got one running